# delete trailing char in line without using string library C

Tags: c, arrays, char

started C this semester and struggling to convert knowledge of java into C. The code compiles and runs but not as I want it. The task is to write a code that read a text file line by line (I have a get line function) and outputs new text file keeping line formatting the same (meaning that if original file has 4 line output file has to have 4 line) but deleting trailing characters (space and \t). I've spend enormous amount of time pocking at this thing without success. **Any help is appreciated.**

hw2_execcise_1. program to remove trailing blanks and tabs from each line of input, and to delete entirely blank lines.

Pseudo::: while (there are lines to read)
          find end of line1 (\n)
          save length
          going from the end of the line towards the beginning
          find char that is not either space or tab
          and insert \n following found char.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define LINELIM 1000


int getLine(char s[], int lim);

int main (void){
    int  len, i;
    char line1[100];

    while ((len = getLine(line1, LINELIM)) >0){

        for (i=len; i>=0; i--){

            if ((line1[i] == ' ') || (line1[i] == '\t')){

                line1[i] = '\n';
            }
            else break;
        }
    printf(" %s\n", line1);
    }

return 0;
}
/*getline: read a line into s, return length*/
int getLine(char s[], int lim){
    int c,i;
    for (i=0; i<lim-1 && (c=getchar())!= EOF && c!='\n'; ++i)
        s[i]=c;
    if (c == '\n'){
        s[i] = c;
        ++i;
    }
    s[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
while ((len = getLine(line1, LINELIM)) >0){
    for (i=len-1; i>=0; i--){//-1 for 0 origin
        if(line1[i] == ' '  || line1[i] == '\t' || line1[i] == '\n'){//add case of '\n'
            line1[i] = '\0';//newline add print part
        }
        else break;
    }
    if(line1[0])//not blank line
        printf("%s\n", line1);
}
```

Comment: tried, still tab and space at the end of first line:
 od -x trim.out
  ........................  0920

Comment: thanks for helping, you tried;-))))
 I have an output file that my output file has to match and....it doesn't((

Comment: try `./a.out < input.txt > out.txt`

Answer (score 0):

the main logic problem with the code is

1) the getline function is terminating each input line with (either) '\n''\0'  or with '\0'

2) the main function is not checking for the newline when it checks for space or tab.  I.E. it needs to also check for newline --or-- getline() should not ever include the newline